# Statement containing indexes, keys and comments with auto_increment

Tags: mysql, sql

I came across the following SQL in a book. I understand all the parts where he is declaring the basics types.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `content` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `current_revision` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `secure` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `parent` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `order` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `author` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `path` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `current_revision` (`current_revision`,`active`,`type`),
  KEY `type` (`type`),
  KEY `author` (`author`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='Content Elements Table' AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

The following is not understood:

```
  KEY `current_revision` (`current_revision`,`active`,`type`),
  KEY `type` (`type`),
  KEY `author` (`author`)
```

I know that "key" is a keyword that is the same as "index" but the way is is used here is unfamiliar to me. Especially with multiple entries like this:

```
KEY `current_revision` (`current_revision`,`active`,`type`)
```

Lastly this is another line I don't know about:

```
ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='Content Elements Table' AUTO_INCREMENT=4;
```

I take it here he is telling it what engine to store the table by and the charset to use, along with a comment. But where is the comment stored and what is "AUTO_INCREMENT=4" doing all the way a the tail end?

Comment: Helpful link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think the keys as index. What is between parenthesis is the column names the index refers to. The `AUTO_INCREMENT=4` means that it sets the `AUTO_INCREMENT` at the value `4`, so that the first inserted records will begin at the stage `4`. `InnoDB` is one of plenty database engines, you'll find docs everywhere ;) here's [some](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_engine), the choice of an engine depends on your need !

Comment: Why is the   KEY `type` (`type`) in this format as opposed to key(type). Why is the word 'type' before the parentheses?

Comment: here http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_index.asp, you'll understand the reason ;) index name is just a way to name, the columns table are targeted in between parenthesis